# simulate delete material-ui Chip

Tags: reactjs, sinon, material-ui, enzyme

I want to write a test, which deletes a material-ui Chip component inside my InputTag component. Any idea how to achieve that? This is my best shot so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import InputTag from '../../src/components/InputTag.js';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import {spy} from 'sinon';

describe('components/InputTag', () => {
    it('should call onRquestDelete method', (done) => {
        const deleteTag = spy();
        const wrapper = mount(
                <InputTag
                    addTag={() => {}}
                    deleteTag={deleteTag}
                    changeTag={() => {}}
                    tags={[{key: "t1", label: "test"}]}
                    tag=""
                />
        );
        expect(wrapper.find('Chip')).toHaveLength(1);

        spy(wrapper.instance(), 'handleRequestDelete'); 
       wrapper.find('Chip').first().find('DeleteIcon').simulate('click');

        expect.assertions(2);
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(wrapper.instance().handleRequestDelete.callCount).toEqual(1);
            expect(deleteTag.callCount).toEqual(1);
            done();
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

The line in question is

> wrapper.find('Chip').first().find('DeleteIcon').simulate('click');

How can I find and click the DeleteIcon or the according action which is handleDeleteIconClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way:

```
    // enzyme does not support touchTap currently
    // @see https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/99
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
        ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(
            wrapper.instance(), 'svg'
        )
    );
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.touchTap(node);
```

not the best shot I guess, as I search for svg in the complete wrapper instance and because I have to search for svg at all, but it works at least

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue testing with Jest and React Testing Library.

Clicking the Chip component did not work.  Also trying to search by role button and firing a click did not work either.

I finally got it to work searching by the class name `.MuiChip-deleteIcon` using the querySelector DOM API.

Here is the code

```
it("should delete the chip component", async () => {
    const { queryByText, container } = render(
      <Chips />
    );

    expect(queryByText("chip1")).toBeDefined();

    const deleteIcon = container.querySelector(".MuiChip-deleteIcon");

    await wait(() => {
      fireEvent.click(deleteIcon);
    });

    await wait(() => {
      expect(queryByText("chip1")).toBeNull();
    });
});
```

Comment: The Chip icon have a data-testid "CancelIcon". Getting the delete icon using screen.getByTestId("CancelIcon") and clicking that works.

Comment: The querySelector works, and I think the `await`s are not necessary

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but for the sake of people who find this question from searches (like me), this is how I fixed it.

I used a mock jest function for easier testing (normally its passed down from the parent component):

```
const handleChipDelete = jest.fn();
```

then I used `page.find("WithStyles(Chip)").prop("onDelete")();` calling the onDelete function, you don't need to test that the DeleteIcon calls the onDelete function because Material-UI tests that, you need to ensure that the onDelete function is called (in my case the onDelete function is tested in the parent component).

This is my full test:

```
it("deletes chips when the delete button is clicked", () => {
      var taggedPost = {
        title: "",
        content: "",
        tags: ["testing"],
        tagField: ""
      };

      const page = shallow(
        <MemoryRouter>
          <PostCreateForm
            post={taggedPost}
            handleFormChange={handleFormChange}
            handleChipDelete={handleChipDelete}
            handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
            postCanBeSubmitted={postCanBeSubmittedTrue}
            loggedIn={loggedIn}
          />
        </MemoryRouter>
      );
      expect(handleChipDelete.mock.calls.length).toEqual(0);
      page.find("WithStyles(Chip)").prop("onDelete")();
      expect(handleChipDelete.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.getByTestId('CancelIcon')
```

[image]

Comment: please do not use code images copy/past it in your answer instead